# Blogger API - Get URL of Scheduled Post

Tags: php, google-api, blogger

I asked this question over on the Blogger Google Group here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bloggerdev/LYBQxsugzlA but haven't had any answers and hoping you knowledgeable folk could help! I have also Googled my ass off and still cant find an answer:

It boils down to me wanting to get the URL that will be used for a scheduled Blogger post when it is published via the API (using the official Blogger PHP client library). If I am making a normal post (unscheduled) like so:

```
 $res = $service->posts->insert('blogger_blog_id', $post_details);
```

I can get the url from the response with

```
 $post_url = $res['url'];
```

But if I schedule the post by adding something like

```
 $post_details->setPublished($date);
```

Before I make the call the url property in the response array just returns the root URL of the blog instead of link to the post.

If I log into Blogger and look at one of these scheduled posts, there is a part of it that gives me the URL that will be used. This is what I want to grab, is it possible?

Comment: what happens if you `sleep(5)` and then fetch the url with a second request?

Comment: Starting to think its not possible to be honest. If I try getting a scheduled post by its ID, I get a 403. Same code with an already published post works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary problem with the Blogger API just in case it happens again!